# react-native why my state is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm starting to learn react-native, and there are some things that i can't understand. This is my file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import SaladsList from './SaladsList';
import salotos from '../Classes/Salads';

export default class SaladsContainer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = { salads: salotos,
                   SaladsDisplayState: true
             };
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }
   changeState() {
      /* if (this.state.SaladsDisplayState === false) {
       this.setState.SaladsDisplayState = true;
      } else if (this.state.saladsDisplayState === true) {
        this.setState.SaladsDisplayState = false;
      }
      console.log(this.state.saladsDisplayState);
      */
      console.log('Veikia funkcija');
      console.log(this.state.salads);
      }
    renderSaladsList() {
      if (this.state.SaladsDisplayState) {
    return this.state.salads.map(salad => <Text style={Styles.saladsText}>{salad.Name}</Text>);
  } else {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeState()}><Text style={Styles.saladsText}>Salotos</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  }
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.SaladsDisplayState);
    return (
      <View style={Styles.saladsContainer}>
      {this.renderSaladsList()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

1.Why when i press button this.state.SaladsDisplayState is not defined? 
2.Why then SaladsDisplayState is defined in Render() section?. 3.Why my this.state.salads is defined everywhere?

Please help me, thank you :)

Comment: `onPress={this.changeState()}` should be `onPress={this.changeState}`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call a function/Method in React Native, from a component just like the TouchableOpacity component, you should use `onPress={() => this.changeState()}` or `onPress={this.changeState}`. If you are juste using `onPress={this.changeState()}`, when the component is pre-rendering, when the code will reach this line, it will execute this code. It will not wait for you to perform a press !